# Is there a way to make a function global to the library and to those who include/link the library?

Tags: c, objective-c, globalization, static-libraries, extern

I'm a bit confused now. I thought that when you used extern on a function, it would become global to everything, but it doesn't seem so... What I want right now, is to have some set of functions that I can use in my static library and in the program that links it. How do I that?
I'm using Objective-C

Comment: You can accept the answer that helped you most by clicking on the check icon under the up/down vote icons of the answer.

Comment: Provide an example of the code you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me, if I just use `extern` instead of `extern inline` when defining the function.

Example: inlib.h

```
extern int foo(int i);
extern int callsfoo(int i);
```

inlib.m:

```
#import "inlib.h"
#import "stdio.h"

extern int foo(int i) { printf("Foo: i = %d\n", i); }

extern int callsfoo(int i) {
    printf("Callsfoo:\n");
    foo(i);
}
```

Library created with: 
`gcc -ObjC -c inlib.m -o inlib.o` 
`ar -q lib.a inlib.o`

caller.m:

```
#import "inlib.h"
#import "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
printf("Calling foo directly.\n");
foo(1);
printf("Calling foo via callsfoo.\n");
callsfoo(2);
return 0;
}
```

Compiled with: `gcc -ObjC -o caller caller.m lib.a -lobjc` 
Run with: `./caller`

Returns:

```
Calling foo directly.
Foo: i = 1
Calling foo via callsfoo.
Callsfoo:
Foo: i = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

On CardDefs.h I have:

```
extern inline
card_config mcc (card_suit s, card_value v, card_points p)
{
    card_config ccfg;
    ccfg.m_suit = s;
    ccfg.m_value = v;
    ccfg.m_points = p;

    return ccfg;
}
```

And I have to use this function inside the library and outside. I have other functions that are similar to this.